# Problem assigning variables

Tags: elisp, variables

Having previously set `emacs-user-directory` thus:

```
(setq user-emacs-directory "~/Dropbox/emacs")
```

I would now want to set `desktop-path` and `desktop-dirname` in this manner:

```
(setq
  desktop-path user-emacs-directory
  desktop-dirname user-emacs-directory
  )
```

However, when I start Emacs and it runs that code (by loading the `desktop` package) I get this error:

```
Wrong type argument: listp, "~/Dropbox/emacs_x"
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: `desktop-path` should be a list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
(setq desktop-path `(,user-emacs-directory "~"))
```

> Documentation:
>   List of directories to search for the desktop file.
>   The base name of the file is specified in `desktop-base-file-name'.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please explain your answer?

Comment: It says in the doc that it should be a list.

Comment: But what does this mean: `(,user-emacs-directory "~")`?

Comment: You can simplify to `(list user-emacs-directory "~")` if you want, it's the same.

Comment: @NVaughan To answer your question, this form ` `(,user-emacs-directory "~")` is a backquoted list. Using backquote instead of quote allows you to have some elements evaluated by prefixing them with a `,`. See https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Backquote.html.